# (React Native): Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, execution

I am generating an apk of a project that I developed using React Native. But when I run the command `./gradlew assembleRelease` The following error appears:

```
> Configure project :react-native-audio
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.

> Task :app:generatePackageList FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\romer\ProjetoAP\Gravador\teste\Gravador_de_audio\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 131

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'.
> argument type mismatch

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 24s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
PS C:\users\romer\ProjetoAP\Gravador\teste\Gravador_de_audio\android>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just ran across the same problem and was able to track down why it was happening on my system. Using the `--stacktrace` flag helped to figure out what was going on, which ended up pointing to the `react-native-community/cli` package.

After scanning the issues and PRs in the `react-native-community/cli` repo, I found this PR https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/1396 which adds support for Gradle 7.

I had Gradle 7 on my system and downgrading to Gradle 6, running `gradle wrapper`, then `./gradlew clean` allowed me to move on.

Hope that solves your issue, or at least gives you some insight on how to track it down on your system!

Comment: Gradle doesnt support Java 16 except version 7.0 for Gradle. 
And react-native-cli doesnt support Gradle 7.0.
What a incredible day :/

Comment: Correction please ./gradlew wrapper

Comment: I am switching back to jdk 8

Comment: @AbdulBasit ´gradlew wrapper´ is for windows users, not everyone uses MAC!

Comment: this didnt work for me: "Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.9."

Comment: Same here: "Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.9" and that's all she wrote.

Comment: @Amit Bravo u can use jdk 11 with no problem

Comment: Was anyone able to make this work with Java 17?

Answer (score 17):

Use Gradle Version 6.9

> Here are the highlights of this release:
>
> - This is a small **backport release**.
> - **Java 16** can be used to compile when used with Java toolchains
> - **Dynamic versions** can be used within plugin declarations
> - Native support for **Apple Silicon processors**

Use Gradle Wrapper to change the Version.

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.9
```

Comment: Thx a lot, saved my day. 
works also with openjdk-17 for me (:

Answer (score 16):

Instead of downgrading, I checked the `reactNativeModule` parameter mentioned at line 131.

It seems like `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>[] packages = this.reactNativeModules`, there is literally a mismatch.

Indeed `reactNativeModule` doesn't have brackets in his declaration.

So I changed the following line in `native_modules.gradle` from:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>[] packages = this.reactNativeModules
```

to:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> packages = this.reactNativeModules
```

Comment: worked for me - what a dub :) and this issue complete bs

Comment: Whoa. Is this an upstream typo? How did it ever work!? Talk about JANKY...I'll go with this for now.

Comment: I don't have the option to downgrade to Gradle < 7 (due to other deps) so tried this, and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: this answer worked for me in two apps :)

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your react-native version to the latest one with `npx react-native upgrade`

I had to upgrade from JDK 1.8 to 11 and this error occurred.

Thanks to J Myers answer I found that I had to upgrade the react native version: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/1396

Answer (score 2):

## Steps to solve it for ***React Native****

1. Find `apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)` in your `app -> build.gradle`.
2. Check if this line of code is being repeated.
3. Comment out one of them.

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing distributionUrl with `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip` in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties fixed everything for me. Thank GOD

Answer (score 1):

For me on `react-native` version `0.70.6`

Issue is due to `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android` version so i just need to run

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

As give [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/1396#issuecomment-1212714258)

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading `@react-native-community/cli` as described here solved the issue for me: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#updating-the-cli

> If you use lock files (yarn.lock or package-lock.json) - find all the
> @react-native-community/cli prefixed entries, remove them, run yarn
> install / npm install once again.