# React Native app in Android studio: Cause Argument type mismatch

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I cant build my app in react native. I started building with cleand project and sync gradle. Everything is okay but when i started building i get The error: "Cause: Argument type mismatch". There is no more description or location where is this error.
[Img of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2ycC.png)

Answer (score 5):

What helped me is to downgrade gradle from 7 to 6.9. You can do that in File->Project structure.

reference:
[(React Native): Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093053/react-native-execution-failed-for-task-appgeneratepackagelist)