# React native gradle build failed

Tags: java, android, react-native

I cloned a `react-native` project from github and below are the steps that I followed in order to make it work on my local ubuntu 20.04 machine:

(The project was expo managed earlier, but now it is ejected because there are `android` and `ios` folders)

1. created my local feature branch -> `git checkout -b feature`
2. installed all the packages in package.json -> `yarn install`
3. ran `npx react-native run-android` to run the app on android emulator

**1st Encountered error**:-

```
Could not write standard input to Gradle build daemon.
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

In order to solve this issue, I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69630720/11685381 answer and removed `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` from my `gradle.properties`

**2nd Encountered error**:-

Again used `npx react-native run-android` and ran into another build error:-

```
* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/home/user/project/android/settings.gradle' (/home/user/.gradle/caches/6.9/scripts/5bii70nilhgbvb8zyo7v963b7).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61
```

To fix this, I used this solution: `https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/BUG!+exception+in+phase+'semantic+analysis'+in+source+unit+'_BuildScript_'+Unsupported+class+file+major+version+61`

**3rd Encountered error**:-

Again ran `npx react-native run-android` and ran into these 2 build error this time:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/user/project/node_modules/expo-gl-cpp/android/build.gradle' line: 307

* What went wrong:
Default side-by-side NDK installation is not found.
Set $ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable correctly or setup ndk.dir in local.properties.
> NDK is not installed

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

To solve the 1st issue i.e. `NDK is not installed` (it is installed though), I created a `local.properties` inside `project/android` directory and pasted the following path:

```
sdk.dir=/home/user/Android/Sdk
ndk.dir=/home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888
```

**4th Encountered error**:-

```
> Task :app:generatePackageList FAILED
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
* Where:
Script '/home/user/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 131

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generatePackageList'.
> argument type mismatch
```

To solve this, I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68180959/11685381 but this again downloaded the `gradle 6.9` which I had earlier also, and again to the **2nd Encountered error**

I've been doing this since 2 days, can someone please help me out here what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `build.grade` from

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
```

To

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
```

It's just an example. try to update Gradle.